# JSon string from Json Object

Tags: json, json.net

How do i get Json string back from json object?
My requirement is such, i parse my string to json object and do some changes to json object
and i want that changes back in to the string

Answer (score 0):

please download  JSON2.js from below link and follow the sample code I have written.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
or
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Add reference to that js file in your project.

### Sample Code:

```
  var address = "India";
  var company = "mindfire";


  //JSON string
  var jsonStr = '{ '
              + '"Address" : '
              + '"' + address + '"'
              + ", "
              + '"Company" : '
              + '"' + company + '"'
              + ' }';

  var addressJson = JSON.parse(jsonStr); //Parse from json string to JSON object

  addressJson.Address = "Bhubaneswar Orissa"; //Change Data in JSON object
  addressJson.Company = "Mindfire Solutions";

  var updatedAddress = JSON.stringify(addressJson); //changes back in to the string from json object


  alert(updatedAddress);
```